# jquery ui connectwith ul in div

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I have a jquery ui list in a div. And i can't get a connection with another list in a div. 
Please help.

[Jsfiddle:](http://jsfiddle.net/hhxpw882/)

There are two lists side by side. The sortable works in each div on his own div. But you can't drag it to the other list.

```
The binding information in javascript:

$( "#itemsHolder" ).sortable({
      connectWith: "#takenHolder",
      placeholder: "ui-state-highlight",

    });


 $( "#takenHolder" ).sortable({
  connectWith: "#itemsHolder",
  placeholder: "ui-state-highlight",


});
```

Can someone solve this?

Comment: Please elaborate about your problem, it's difficult to understand what you are asking.

Comment: Seems like you are trying to achieve, what's here! http://jsfiddle.net/KyleMit/Geupm/2/

Comment: @KamranAhmed Yes thats what i want. but i can't get that workend in my code.

Comment: @BinaryTox1n I have 2 lists both are in a div. i want to drag items from list 1 to list 2. But since they are in div's i cant get it worked. i have seen examples but can't get them working on my code. Thats why i post the fiddle

Comment: Hey @JohnnydeWitte, welcome to StackOverflow (SO). Please read [ask]. There are many SOers who can't/won't click on links to other sites because they are blocked in a work environment. Please copy whatever you put in the jsfiddle into your question, otherwise you risk it being closed as 'not clear what you're asking'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that your `.item` has a `float` property. `connectWith` doesn't work with floated elements.

Just remove `float: left;` from `.item`. See the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/hhxpw882/2/

Comment: You are my personal hero. its work. thank you so much!!